# Libgdx scene2dui column sizing issue

Tags: libgdx, scene2d, scrollpane

I was making a level table in libgdx using scroll pane. here there are different tables with specific level on a particular scroll pane. Is there any way to preset a particular table to be the first one I see, becuase it would be stupid if I have more than 50 level and I have to scroll through all of them to go to a particular level at end.

A brief details about my tables and scrollpane.

I have a arraylist of table called as column table, which is used as to store different level details in different columns. then this column table is added to another table which is called as levleTable.

The level table is added to scrollpane which is added to main table.

```
public void setScrollPane() {
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelTable, getScrollPaneStyle());
    // scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelTable, skin);
    //scrollPane.setFlickScroll(true);
    scrollPane.setFadeScrollBars(false);
    scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(false, true);
    scrollPane.setScrollX(300);
    scrollPane.updateVisualScroll();
    //scrollPane.setSmoothScrolling(true);
    mainTable.add(scrollPane).expand();
}
```

and in constructor`

```
    mainTable = new Table();
    mainTable.setFillParent(true);
    levelTable = new Table();
    setScrollPane();
    columnTable = new ArrayList<Table>();
    levelSelectionButton = new ArrayList<TextButton>();
    makeLevelMenu();

    //adding main table to stage
    stage.addActor(mainTable);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the the better idea (when using mechanism like this) i to scroll the scrollPane automatically to the current object (which could be the table with  your next level for example).

You can easily achieve it using:

```
    scrollPane.setScrollY(y);
```

where the y should be

```
y = (total height of scroll Pane content) - ( (desired element Y position inside scrollPane) - (element height) )
```

I mean that if your scrollPane content has 100px height and there are 5 elements every with 20px height then scrolling to the third is:

```
y = 100 - (3 * 20px - 20px) = 100 - 40px = 60px
```

The same will work if your scrollPane is arranged horizontally - you just need to use scrollPane.setScrollX(x) and calculates all width instead of heights

UPDATE: **before using setScrollX / setScrollY you have to call .layout() method on the scrollPane**

---

The example:

```
    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
        //creating stage and viewport
        viewport = new FillViewport(1280, 800);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        //creating levelTable
        Table levelTable = new Table();
        levelTable.setSize(2000, 500);

        //filling levelTable with fake actors (it can be labels of your levels numbers)
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Actor a = new Actor();
            a.setSize(80, 200);

            //set debug to see the outline
            a.debug();

            levelTable.add(a).pad(150, 10, 150, 10);
        }

        //set debug to see the outline
        levelTable.debug();

        //defining scroll
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelTable, skin);

        scrollPane.setSize(800, 600); //your custom size
        scrollPane.setPosition(50, 50); //your custom position

        scrollPane.setFadeScrollBars(false);
        scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(false, true);

        //important!! you have to call it before setScrollX
        scrollPane.layout(); //that's the thing!

        //the number of column you want to go to
        int numberOfColumn = 10;

        //now move to column no numberOfColumn
        scrollPane.setScrollX( levelTable.getWidth() - ( levelTable.getColumns() - numberOfColumn - 1 ) * 100 ); //100, because column width is 100 - actor = 80 + 2 * 10 pad

        //set debug to see the outline
        scrollPane.debug();

        this.stage.addActor(scrollPane);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the content width totally, sorry i didn't mentioned it before but my table are arranged horixontally.

Comment: check the update how to calculate whole height/width

Comment: sorry man! I am unable to set scrollX. it is just not moving.

Comment: it should be working - I use the same in my project but with Y. Did you try to setScrollX() with some hardcoded parameter? Try to call .setScrollX(100), .setScrollX(-100), .setScrollX(20) etc and see if it working at all - also where you are trying to setScrollX() - is it called for sure? Last thing is to try to comment setFlick... and other "sets" - maybe one of them is blocking this?

Comment: yes I did - as I said I'm not very sure about "set..." function - I only used setScrollingDisabled - maybe here is something wrong? You can try to use also **container.setScrollPercentX(percentX);** instead of setScrollX() **not setX() - sorry for mistake in upper comment**

Comment: ok last thing - please update question with the code how are you updateing scroll - to be honest whole Screen class code would be the best

Comment: give me some time. i will get back to you.

Comment: i have added extra details

Comment: i want to but it would be a huge mess and you won't understand anything, ask me other details. for ex. i have now removed the main table and setting the scroll pane to fill the screen, and added that scroll pane to stage.

Comment: can you show me your code, by that way I will be able to compare or find out my mistake

Comment: I guess I figured it out - it was about calling **.layout()** method before call setScrollX() - check out the update and the code

Comment: although your code is not working in my code, but i have tested your code and its working. so what i will do is try to adapt your code in mine. thanks for keeping with me.

Comment: great :) you can mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question so the next person will find the resolution faster - regards!

Comment: ya sure. for more info I have used different way in where i use scrollTo method of scrollPane.